# How to disable Cache in Firefox for the localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, firefox

I have a little problem I'm working on a react app using the localhost:3000 to see the differences. But for some of the changes like the favicon, it didn't update until I clear the cache for this url in firefox. So my question is there is a way to stop firefox from saving the cache for this specific url without disabling it completely for every website?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable cache temporarily by opening developer tools, press F1 to open dev tool settings, scroll down and enable Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open), however this will only take effect when dev tools is open